# jQuery inArray function not grabbing value on change select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show an element if a specific value in a *select* is selected:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#add_category3").change(function() {

            var id = $(this).val();

            if (jQuery.inArray(id, vehicles) !== -1)
                $("#vehicle-fields").show();
             else
                $("#vehicle-fields").hide();

            console.log(id);

        });
    });
```

It works fine if I change the variable *id* for the actual value in the inArray() function (hardcoring the value), but it doesn't when I use the variable *id*.

The console.log(id) gives back the actual value that makes que element show up, so I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Sounds like `id` has some whitespace or something in it. Try doing `id === hardCodedValue` to prove this to yourself. Then check the length of `id`. It's probably longer than the hardcoded value.

Comment: what does `console.log(id)` shows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're having a type issue to me. You have to remember that inArray is type sensitive. So your val() is coming through as a string (most likely), but the array has int arrays you'll always get a -1 return on inArray. Cast this.val() call to an int

```
parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function inArray(arrays,id){
  var inarray = false;
    for (var i = 0, l = arrays.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (arrays[i] == id) {
        inarray = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  return inarray;
}
```

use your own custom inArray. Because inarray doesn't compare string values to integers.

```
$(function () {
    $("#add_category3").change(function() {

        var id = $(this).val();

        if (inArray(vehicles,id))
            $("#vehicle-fields").show();
         else
            $("#vehicle-fields").hide();

        console.log(id);

    });
});
```

Comment: This answer works too, it was about the type. Thank you very much but i chose the best answer from programndial for being simpler

Answer (score 0):

try to use trim(id), may be some whitespacing is there

Answer (score -1):

This is not work because of you use !== in if condition. 
Try != in if condition and it will work. Use below code which I improved your code.

```
$(function () {
    $("#add_category3").change(function() {

        var id = $(this).val();

        if (jQuery.inArray(id, vehicles) != -1)
            $("#vehicle-fields").show();
         else
            $("#vehicle-fields").hide();

        console.log(id);

    });
});
```

Comment: `!==` will work, because `inArray()` returns a number, and `-1` is a number, so there's no coercion.